# Elements are not identified in microsoft edge and safari browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, microsoft-edge, safaridriver

Elements are not identified in microsoft edge and safari browsers but its getting identified with chrome, ie and firefox.

`By.xpath("//div[@class='linkedUserName']")`. 
Even with `By.className("linkedUserName")`

```
Selenium: 3.14.0
Edge version: 41.16299.726.0(As per OS build) 
Safari:11.1 (High Sierra)
```

Any workarounds / solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: did u tried css selector, it may work ?

Comment: Hello, please visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask center, to understand how to ask a question. To receive a proper answer we have to understand your question.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Depending on the site, the HTML rendered may actually be different on Edge and Safari vs Chrome, IE, and FF. Have you tested the locator on Edge and Safari using the dev tools to make sure it's good there?